# Python & Pandas: iterate through rows to set value

Tags: python, json, pandas

In my `dataframe`, I have a column with `json/dict` in it, I want to iterate through rows to extract some value, add it to a new column.
Here is what the data look like, notice `omdb` is a `dict`
[image]

I'm doing this, extracting the `imdbRating` out to a standalone column, but it gives me `keyerror`

```
pd_data['imdbRating'] = 0 
for index, row in pd_data.iterrows():
    row['imdbRating'] =row['omdb_info']['imdbRating']
```

So, what's the correct way of extracting the value?

Addtionally, I can get this working:

```
for index, row in pd_data[:10].iterrows():
    pd_data.ix[index,'imdbRating']  = row['omdb_info']['imdbRating']
```

UPDATE: 
Now I think it should be data problem, maybe some `row['omdb_info']` does not have `['imdbRating']`? or do not have `row['omdb_info']` at all, how can I search for its existance?

```
# this work
for index, row in pd_data[:118].iterrows():
    pd_data.ix[index,'imdbRating']  = row['omdb_info']['imdbRating']
# this do not work
for index, row in pd_data[:119].iterrows():
    pd_data.ix[index,'imdbRating']  = row['omdb_info']['imdbRating']

print pd_data.ix[118]['omdb_info']['imdbRating'] # => 6.8
print pd_data.ix[119]['omdb_info']['imdbRating'] # => 6.9
print pd_data.ix[120]['omdb_info']['imdbRating'] # => 5.5
```

The error it reports

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-143-a0ae169ddfe9> in <module>()
      9 # this do not work
     10 for index, row in pd_data[:119].iterrows():
---> 11     pd_data.ix[index,'imdbRating']  = row['omdb_info']['imdbRating']

KeyError: 'imdbRating'
```

Addtionally, Where can I upload the data file, so you can take a look at it?

Comment: could you include the stack trace

Comment: @JeremyFisher I've added the report, not sure if this is the `stack trace`

Comment: Yes that was the stack trace. So rows 119 and 120 exist but you are saying that iterating past 118 causes an error. Is this still a keyError or a different error?

Comment: @JeremyFisher, I just add that, still the `key error`, really have no idea about it.

Comment: If you're not sure if the value exists, use `x.get('imdbRating', None)` rather than `x['imdbRating']`, and then it'll have `None` if there's no value there. (You can also replace `None` with `np.nan` if you prefer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid iterating, if possible, and instead find a function to apply, such as this:

```
pd_data['imdbRating'] = pd_data['omdb_info'].apply(lambda x: x['imdbRating'])
```

Comment: It gives me another error, and I've includede in the update. I don't know what's wrong with that. A possible reason maybe the `nan` data? but I've already drop dulicate and na

Comment: @mdurant: I like this solution, but wouldn't `.map` be better? Or if you're going to use apply on a single series, you need to include an `axis` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that instead of iteration, you could try simply accessing the value of the dictionary in `omdb_info` and adding it to a new column with a single operation.

```
pd_data['imdb_rating'] = pd_data['omdb_info']['imdbRating']
```

I believe for what you're trying to do you may not need to iterate, but I admittedly haven't worked with DataFrames in a while.

Comment: Yes, and now I know it is indeed a data issue.